# Displaying Data from MySQL DB into ListView using AsynTask generates FATAL ERROR : AsyncTask : #1

Tags: android, mysql, android-asynctask

I found a [TUTORIEL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) that could help me .. this one uses MySQL Database to get data and display it in a ListView control .. The problem is that I get errors when dealing with AsyncTask .. So this is my personal code and the Error Report

```
   package pre.commande;

   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.MenuItem;
   import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.HashMap;
   import java.util.List;

   import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
   import org.json.JSONArray;
   import org.json.JSONException;
   import org.json.JSONObject;


   import android.app.ListActivity;
   import android.app.ProgressDialog;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.AsyncTask;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.AdapterView;
   import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
   import android.widget.ListAdapter;
   import android.widget.ListView;
   import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
   import android.widget.TextView;

   public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {



// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> produitList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_products = "http://10.0.2.2/precommande/ts_produit.php";


// JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUIT = "produit";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_DES = "des";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray produit = null;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Hashmap for ListView
            produitList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            // Loading products in Background Thread
            new LoadAllProducts().execute();

            // Get listview
            ListView lv = getListView();

   }



   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
       return true;
   }


   /**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                produit = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUIT);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < produit.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = produit.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String des = c.getString(TAG_DES); 

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_DES, des);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    produitList.add(map);
                }
            } 
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        MainActivity.this, produitList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_ID,
                                TAG_DES},
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

    }


}
```

ERROR REPORT

> 08-06 11:07:04.979: D/dalvikvm(1347):         GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 43K, 51% free 2669K/5379K, external 1541K/1559K, paused 132ms
>   08-06 11:07:05.369: W/System.err(1347):     java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
>   08-06 11:07:05.369: W/System.err(1347):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.socket(Native Method)
>   08-06 11:07:05.369: W/System.err(1347):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.socket(BlockGuard.java:335)
>   08-06 11:07:05.369: W/System.err(1347):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:216)
>   08-06 11:07:05.369: W/System.err(1347):     at java.net.Socket.checkOpenAndCreate(Socket.java:802)
>   08-06 11:07:05.369: W/System.err(1347):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:948)
>   08-06 11:07:05.379: W/System.err(1347):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
>   08-06 11:07:05.379: W/System.err(1347):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:143)
>   08-06 11:07:05.379: W/System.err(1347):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
>   08-06 11:07:05.459: W/System.err(1347):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
>   08-06 11:07:05.459: W/System.err(1347):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
>   08-06 11:07:05.459: W/System.err(1347):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
>   08-06 11:07:05.459: W/System.err(1347):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
>   08-06 11:07:05.459: W/System.err(1347):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
>   08-06 11:07:05.459: W/System.err(1347):     at pre.commande.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:62)
>   08-06 11:07:05.459: W/System.err(1347):     at pre.commande.MainActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:105)
>   08-06 11:07:05.459: W/System.err(1347):     at pre.commande.MainActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
>   08-06 11:07:05.459: W/System.err(1347):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
>   08-06 11:07:05.459: W/System.err(1347):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
>   08-06 11:07:05.469: W/System.err(1347):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>   08-06 11:07:05.469: W/System.err(1347):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
>   08-06 11:07:05.469: W/System.err(1347):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
>   08-06 11:07:05.469: W/System.err(1347):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
>   08-06 11:07:05.469: E/Buffer Error(1347):   Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
>   08-06 11:07:05.469: E/JSON Parser(1347):    Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
>   08-06 11:07:05.491: W/dalvikvm(1347):       threadid=8: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb67714f0)
>   08-06 11:07:05.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1347): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>   08-06 11:07:05.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>   08-06 11:07:05.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
>   08-06 11:07:05.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
>   08-06 11:07:05.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
>   08-06 11:07:05.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
>   08-06 11:07:05.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>   08-06 11:07:05.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
>   08-06 11:07:05.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
>   08-06 11:07:05.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
>   08-06 11:07:05.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1347): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   08-06 11:07:05.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     at pre.commande.MainActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:108)
>   08-06 11:07:05.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     at pre.commande.MainActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
>   08-06 11:07:05.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
>   08-06 11:07:05.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
>   08-06 11:07:05.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     ... 4 more
>   08-06 11:07:05.528: D/gralloc_goldfish(1347):   Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
>   08-06 11:07:06.318: E/WindowManager(1347):  Activity pre.commande.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@b6c6afc0 that was originally added here
>   08-06 11:07:06.318: E/WindowManager(1347):  android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity pre.commande.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@b6c6afc0 that was originally added here
>   08-06 11:07:06.318: E/WindowManager(1347):  at android.view.ViewRoot.(ViewRoot.java:258)
>   08-06 11:07:06.318: E/WindowManager(1347):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
>   08-06 11:07:06.318: E/WindowManager(1347):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
>   08-06 11:07:06.318: E/WindowManager(1347):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
>   08-06 11:07:06.318: E/WindowManager(1347):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
>   08-06 11:07:06.318: E/WindowManager(1347):  at pre.commande.MainActivity$LoadAllProducts.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:95)
>   08-06 11:07:06.318: E/WindowManager(1347):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
>   08-06 11:07:06.318: E/WindowManager(1347):  at pre.commande.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:64)
>   08-06 11:07:06.318: E/WindowManager(1347):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   08-06 11:07:06.318: E/WindowManager(1347):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
>   08-06 11:07:06.318: E/WindowManager(1347):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
>   08-06 11:07:06.318: E/WindowManager(1347):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
>   08-06 11:07:06.318: E/WindowManager(1347):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
>   08-06 11:07:06.318: E/WindowManager(1347):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   08-06 11:07:06.318: E/WindowManager(1347):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>   08-06 11:07:06.318: E/WindowManager(1347):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
>   08-06 11:07:06.318: E/WindowManager(1347):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   08-06 11:07:06.318: E/WindowManager(1347):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   08-06 11:07:06.318: E/WindowManager(1347):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   08-06 11:07:06.318: E/WindowManager(1347):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>   08-06 11:07:06.318: E/WindowManager(1347):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Have you added a permission in your android manifest file.

Comment: NO !! i did not edited the manifest file !! how to do it plz ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

above `<application>` tag.